# How to prove the following results for $H$-bimodule $V$?

Tags: hopf-algebras

Suppose $(H, \cdot, \eta, \Delta,\varepsilon,S)$ be a Hopf algebra, and $V$ be a (finite-dimensional) $H$-bimodule.

Then, how can we prove $\alpha\dot{}h-h.\alpha = 0$ for all $h \in H$ if we have $\alpha \in V$ which satisfy $$\mathrm{S}h_{(1)}.\alpha \dot{} h_{(2)} - \varepsilon(h)\alpha = 0$$ for all $h \in H$, where $.$ is a left $H$-action and $\dot{}$ is a right $H$-action on $V$?

Is it possible? or if it's impossible, is there a known condition that $V$ and $\alpha$ must satisfy?

Comment: What is the relationship between $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$?

Comment: @Berci Thanks for pointing out. It's an typo. $\alpha$ is correct.

Comment: Can you prove it or find counterexample in the specific case $H$ is a group algebra?

Comment: @Berci Yes, it's just the rewriting of the $g^{-1}.\alpha\dot{}g = \alpha$ for $g \in G$ if $H$ is $kG$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I think I can approach to the proof.

By the condition, we can apply the result on each $h_{(2)}$ and have
$$
h_{(1)}.Sh_{(2)}.\alpha \dot{}h_{(3)} = \varepsilon(h_{(2)}) h_{(1)}.\alpha 
$$

It is equivalent to
$$
\alpha\dot{}h = \varepsilon(h_{(1)})\alpha\dot{}h_{(2)} = \varepsilon(h_{(2)}) h_{(1)}\dot{}\alpha = h\dot{}\alpha
$$ by the properties of $\varepsilon$ in Hopf algebra $H$.